# Detecting Malicious Web Pages using Machine Learning

Tags: security, web, deep-learning, malware-detection

I'm looking to develop an application which will detect malicious web pages. I'm thinking of a browser extension. So, I started to look for some research papers and found the below one.

[A Deep Learning Approach to detecting Malicious Javascript code - Wang et. al](https://onlinelibrary.wiley.com/doi/full/10.1002/sec.1441)

Though this seems good enough, I cannot find the link to source code. How do I get the source code for a research paper?

Are there any other such promising papers with source code that I can use?

Answer (score 1):

This paper is about how to train a model, which is the heart of machine learning systems. The "source code" is generally a standard engine like TensorFlow. What you need is a large corpus of labeled examples of malicious javascript and non-malicious javascript. Collecting, labeling, and building a model based on that corpus is the project you're describing; the executable source code is a minor detail, and you'll probably use TensorFlow, at least to get started, because everyone uses TensorFlow. ("Use TensorFlow to build an ML system" is the equivalent of saying "use C to build an operating system." It is not intended to be a description of how to actually build the thing; building this thing is a major undertaking.)

The main artifact in the paper you link is the "over 27 000 labeled samples." I do not believe they have released that corpus (let alone the trained model) to the public. The paper is describing how you would go about building your own model based on your own samples.

If this kind of thing interests you, start with the TensorFlow tutorials. Learn how to classify flowers (because that's what everyone starts with). Then learn how to classify computer languages (Java vs Swift vs Haskell). With that experience, I believe this paper will make more sense to you. (It's still pretty advanced, but at least you'll know what your problem looks like.)

Comment: I have some practice with TensorFlow. I have been following only tutorials all these days and I want to do something more especially in the field of Security. Detecting malicious URLs was one of the projects which I wanted to do and this paper was really interesting. Leave the source code. I can try it out myself but the dataset is the problem. I may not be able to generate the proper dataset described in the paper.

Comment: I definitely understand that creating this dataset is challenging. That's the entire heart of the problem you're trying to solve. If this were an easy problem, then the browsers would just filter malicious javascript before it ran. Given the commercial value of such datasets, and the value for malicious writers to use a publicly trained model to make sure their script isn't detected, I am not surprised that these models are not easily obtained for free. You have picked a very interesting and extremely challenging problem to explore.